# unable to do routing using react getting errors as Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi i am a newbie to react what i am trying is to navigate from one component to another and for that i used the below logic

```
class App extends Component {
  getData(){
    this.props.history.push('/test-data');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ReactJS</h1>
        <div >
          <button  id="data" onClick={this.getData}>test data</button>
          <button  id="con">test info</button>
        </div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Route path="/test-data" component={TestData} />
              <Route path="/test-info" component={TestInfo} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

when ever i try to navigate to the page  i am getting below error

```
Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

below is my stackblitz code :-https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xtshvq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the code.
Change `getData` to an arrow function. And to access `history`, you need to wrap your component in `withRouter` HOC.

Here is the working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jmgjf4?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TestData from './test-data/test-data';
import TestInfo from './test-info/test-info';

class App extends Component {
  getData = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/test-data');
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h1>ReactJS</h1>
        <div >
          <button id="data" onClick={this.getData}>test data</button>
          <button id="con">test info</button>
        </div>

        <div>

          <Route path="/test-data" component={TestData} />
          <Route path="/test-info" component={TestInfo} />
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App)

const AppContainer = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppWithRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: mayi know why separate const AppContainer = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppWithRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

Comment: It is there just to wrap the `App` component in `BrowserRouter`. In future, you can add all the app level providers here.

Answer (score 0):

Error Wrap `<BrowserRouter>` in index.js as

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

For demo Application check this [link](https://blog.pshrmn.com/entry/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the error by adding the following code to the App class:

```
constructor() {
  this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
}
```

The problem is the `this` keyword. In JavaScript it's really confusing and leads to those issues. When you pass the function `this.getData` to the button component, it tries to execute it within the scope of the button component which then fails.

What the above code does is it basically tells the function to use the passed variable as the internal `this` inside the function.

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined if i added it in the contructor

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't have a prop `history` where you could call `push` on. You might want to look at `<Link>` in react-router though as this is the recommended way of links

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `getData` function is not bound to the `this` context, so it can´t access `this.props`. You have to either bind it or use an arrow function:

```
// Bind it in the constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
}

// Or use arrow function
getData = () => {};
```

2. Your `App` component has no access to the `history` prop because it never gets any props. To change this you have to move your `BrowserRouter` outside of the `App` component. You can add it at `ReactDOM.render`. Then you have to wrap your `App` component with the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router` and use that wrapped component as a child of the `BrowserRouter` component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><AppWithRouter /></BrowserRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```